# What does the Red X mean in the Flask run configuration in PyCharm 2018.3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am using the latest version of PyCharm (2018.3.3).  I created a flask project and worked on it for a little while before I noticed the red X in the build configuration drowp-down button.  It gives no indication that I can see that the project is broken.  I can run it and it functions.  I would ignore it, but I teach and I know *somebody* is going to ask what that means.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2sRI.png)

I did notice when creating a new Flask server run configuration that the new one has the red X too, and there is a warning that says "Requires Flask 0.12 or higher".  When PyCharm created the project it pulled the latest version of Flask (1.0.2) which should certainly meet the version requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be a PyCharm bug, but to begin with make sure the Flask server Run Configuration uses the project interpreter as in principe one can select a different one there with no `flask` installed. Also try to invalidate PyCharm caches with **File | Invalidate Caches & Restart**.

[image]

Comment: You know how it is, you ask a question on Friday and on Monday the error is gone...  But I fiddled around with that drop down you pointed out and was able to reproduce the problem.  I must have clicked it by accident or something and set it to another environment.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. It is caused either by;

- Selecting an interpreter **without flask installed** in it.
- The **configuration being unable to find flask**(although it is
  installed)

The First thing to check is whether you have selected the right interpreter. If so, check if you have flask installed (`pip freeze`). If you have flask installed and have the same issue follow these steps to resolve it;

- Uninstall flask (`pip uninstall flask`)
- Reinstall flask (`pip install flask`)
- Go back to the edit configuration and select the python interpreter now.

You are set to go. Happy coding!